# How to pass an object between two JVM in java?

Tags: java, serialization, jvm

Recently I was asked this question in an interview: how can you pass an object between two JVMs? My response was using serialization, but I don't know if it's the right answer. How else could an object be passed between two JVMs?

Comment: Through an agreed upon protocol, which may well be basic `Serialization`.

Comment: Doutbful whether it's a correct answer why? You could mention RMI which is built on top of Serialization; also JSON, XML, and numerous others of that ilk.

Comment: @Amit This question was asked many times on SO. Please, use search before posting.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov when there is a duplicate, you should click `close` with the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Serialization is the perhaps only way out. Depending on your stack you could have one of the several possibilities

- serialize class and deserialize them on the other end (remember remote ejb's)
- write an object to a file (json etc) and read it on the other end from shared folder
- or use use mciroservices to send and receive objects
- you could also try out tools like protobuf, avro as they tackle the serialization problem specifically

My personal preference would be to have a small server side component (a service) for exchanging data.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass Java Objects between 2 JVMs in a distributed environment as long as both the versions of JVMs are identical. Please note, your JVM is platform dependent (Platform includes Hardware (Processor)  + OS). However, you need to make sure all dependent library files are available on both JVMs. Another drawback is that even if your JVMs are the same, the object passing is of no use if you are passing Java object running in one JVM to JRuby running in receiving JVM as the data types are different between the 2.

If if JVMs are same and all libraries are available, object passing is not recommended as you might decide to upgrade on OS from 32 bit to 64 bit and in that case, you need to upgrade JVM as well.

Object passing is something i prefer only within the same JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the object externally. Instead of a file you can go with a fast access data structure store like redis https://redis.io/ . Both(or more) the instances can read and write data to the same data store. You can also look into JMS(Java Messaging Service)